# React componentdidmount return state with outside function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm getting data from an API but I cant seem to get an onClick listener to work with the returned results

```
  async componentDidMount() {
    const response = await fetch('/api/mediabuys');
    await response.json().then(data => {
      let markets = data.mediabuys.map(function(item)  {
        return(
          <tr key={item.id}>
            <td onClick={this.openWindow.bind(this)}>{item.name}</td>
          </tr>
        )
      })
      this.setState({markets: markets});
    })
  }

  openWindow() {
    console.log('a');
  }
```

and the error im getting is:

`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'openWindow' of undefined`

if I add in `this.openWindow` to the beginning of ComponentDidMount, its able to run the function and I also have `this.openWindow = this.openWindow.bind(this)` in the constructor. How can I get the onClick to see the function?

Comment: You should store data.mediaBuys in state instead of jsx and then map that data in render function, that will be better approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're currently binding to the local scope. Change:

```
function(item)  {
```

To:

```
(item) => {
```

The arrow function will allow you to access the parent scope.

Answer (score 1):

change

```
 function(item)  {
```

to

```
 item => {
```

to prevent loosing context.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to bind `this` twice, so it's enough to just pass `this.openWindow` to the onClick attribute.
https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html
Also `function` literal will not bind `this` so you need to use the new arrow syntax to pass a function for the `map`.

Answer (score 0):

Bind the anonymous function you passed to `.map` with `this`. Or use an *Arrow* function.

```
let markets = data.mediabuys.map(function (item) {
  return (
    <tr key={item.id}>
      <td onClick={this.openWindow}>{item.name}</td>
    </tr>
  )
}.bind(this))
```

Or,

```
let markets = data.mediabuys.map( (item) => {
  return (
    <tr key={item.id}>
      <td onClick={this.openWindow}>{item.name}</td>
    </tr>
  )
})
```

Both way, function passed to the `map` function will have access to the outer context `this`.